# Why would you ever add 10^9+7 to a number and then take mod with 10^9+7

Tags: c++, math, modulo, long-long, fenwick-tree

I was solving a problem of Fenwick tree named shill and wave sequence and it wasn't passing all the test cases until I added a line looking at the solution and now want to find its purpose ,here is my code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define mod 1000000007
long long query(long long index,int p,long long **bit)
{
    long long count=0;
    for(;index>0;index-=(index&(-index)))
    {
        count=(count+bit[index][p])%mod;
    }
    return count;
}
void update(long long **bit,long long index,int p,long long val)
{
    for(;index<=100000;index+=(index&(-index)))
    {
        bit[index][p]=(bit[index][p]+val)%mod;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    long long ans=0;
    long long **bit=new long long*[100000+1];
    for(int i=1;i<=100000;i++)
    {
        bit[i]=new long long[3];
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            bit[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        long long x;
        cin>>x;
        long long a=(query(x-1,0,bit)+query(x-1,2,bit))%mod;
        long long b=(query(100000,1,bit)+query(100000,2,bit))%mod-query(x,1,bit)-query(x,2,bit);
        b=(b+mod)%mod;
//WHAT IS THE PURPOSE OF ABOVE LINE?
        ans+=(a+b)%mod;
        update(bit,x,0,b);
        update(bit,x,1,a);
        update(bit,x,2,1);
    }
    cout<<ans%mod;
    return 0;
}
```

b=(b+mod)%mod
but why?

Comment: It may have sense if `b` is negative ! `%` is not a modulo operator, but a remainder operator.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be fundamentally a math and/or computer science question, not a programming question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It’s very obviously programming *related* — especially since, if you take this as a pure maths question, the answer would be *different*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This is a question about the behaviour of operator `%`. It is worth noting that `a % b` differs differently in most programming languages, on the four possible combinations of signs (a positive, b positive), (a negative, b positive), (a positive, b negative), (a negative, b negative). So, this question would have a different answer for every different programming language. If such a question isn't suited for stackoverflow, then I don't know what question would be.

Answer (score 2):

For some cases `b` can be negative and may cause incorrect results while doing `%` directly. That's why before doing `%` operation it's safe to add `mod` and then do `%` which will make the number positive first and then do the modulo.

Comment: Adding mod doesn't make the answer positive necessarily though? For example if b is -5 and mod is 3, adding mod makes it -2.

Still you may be right that this was the intention (and might work in this specific case).

Comment: ```b``` can never be ```-5``` if ```mod``` is 3. The OP is doing ```b = (b + mod) % mod``` every time. So the value of b can't be ```-5``` @user32149

Answer (score -1):

The "purpose" of the line (or rather, the reason that it has any effect) could be that

> b=(b+mod)%mod;

changes the value of b.

So the remaning question is, does it matter that you add "mod" before applying %mod?

Mathematically speaking

> (x+y) mod y = x mod y

However, in many programming languages, there is a maximum value of int and if you add up something too big, you get an integer overflow.
In that case, it can easily happen that

> (x+y) mod y != x mod y

which could be the case for you.

Comment: It is not the problem here. `b` can be negative. For example, `-2 % 5 = -2` and `(-2 + 5) % 5 = 3`. `%` is not really a modulo operator.

Comment: There is very few occasions that overflowing is intended behavior. Let alone achieving it by using such a way.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.